# iPhone App images not loading on cellular data

Tags: iphone, xcode

Imade an app, with a table showing images from a url.

It works fine in almost all iphone models, except iphone 6 plus, with cellular data the images are not showing, but if i connect the same phone to wifi, the images load ok

any help?

thanks

Comment: did u try looking into the app settings on device, and let it allow to access the cellular data ?

Comment: yes, the settings on device are ok, cellular data enabled

Comment: did u check the cellular data for the app itself ? not the cellular data for the whole device.

Comment: Please try this "
SDImageCache" https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: i am using SDImageCache